# Count the records based on value of columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, filter

I have the below df:

```
ID  Col1 Col2 Col3
1    A    NB    C
2    A    NB    C 
3    NS   B     NC
4    NS   NB    NC
5    NS   B     NC
6    NS    B     C
```

And I'm trying to get the count of each column based on their values.

How many "A" are in the Col1

How many "B" are in the Col2

How many "C" are in the Col3

In the original df I have a lot of column and conditions.

The expected output:

```
Col1                Col2            Col3         
TotalCount"A"   TotalCount"B"    TotalCount"C"
```

So, I'm trying to get the list of columns and iterate it but I am not getting the expected results.
I'm working with pandas in jupyternotebook

Comment: Please post your expected output.

Comment: removed tag `jupyter-notebook` as this question has nothing to do with jupyter-notebook.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`df.eq`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.eq.html) here and pass a list of values to compare against.

```
values = ['A', 'B', 'C']
out = df.loc[:, 'Col1':].eq(values).sum()

Col1    2
Col2    3
Col3    3
dtype: int64
```

Answer (score 1):

Extending on @Ch3ster's answer to match the expected output:

```
In [1382]: values = ['A', 'B', 'C']
In [1391]: res = df.filter(like='Col', axis=1).eq(values).sum().to_frame().T

In [1392]: res
Out[1392]: 
   Col1  Col2  Col3
0     2     3     3
```